# What happened to the Dothraki in S08E06?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the season 8 finale of *Game of Thrones*, we see the Dothraki besides the Unsullied but after

> Jon murders Daenerys

they vanish! What did they do about it? Where did they go? How did they react?

Answer (score 19):

They don't just vanish. We do see them when Jon is lead to the docks to be taken to the Wall.

[image]

They have their signature arraks in hand. You can see Jon in the background.

Seeing as they are near the docks, it seems to me that they are heading back to Essos maybe to their homeland in Vaes Dothrak. They are not with the Unsullied because Unsullied are traveling to Naath to keep peace. Maybe Dothraki boarded other ships bound for Essos.

Comment: Right. I noticed them after I rewatched. But it still doesn't explain how and why they don't claim justice for their queen.

Comment: @Nitwit the Dothraki don't seem to care much for defeated Khal's or Khaleesi in this case. If one leader gets killed they follow another & move on. They abandoned Drogo because he fell from a horse. They follow strength not loyalty

Comment: I also find it unlikely they'd stay in Westros with Dany gone.  (They may be the world's finest light cavalry, but Westeros is full of Knights--heavy cavalry--and the Dothraki remnants would surely eventually be overcome.)

Answer (score 9):

**They scattered into Westeros.**

When Khal Drogo died, his Khalasar abandoned Dany immediately. They only follow strength, and "A Khal who cannot ride is no Khal". When Dany died, they probably abandoned her cause just as quickly.

We see that the Unsullied take the ships, and we don't see any Dothraki on them.

The Dothraki must be exploring Westeros - probably with a new Khal and nothing to stop them from attacking cities and enslaving their citizens.

Comment: This seems likely, but the feel of the ending suggests to me that they returned (off-screen) to Essos and the Dothraki Sea.  Bran was concerned about Drogon, but nobody had any cares at all about uncontrolled Dothraki hordes.

Comment: This is an opinion. not a fact, since we don't see anything of them. they just disappear. also, how did they face the fact that Jon killed their queen? why didn't they claim justice just as the unsullied did?

Comment: @Nitwit, also, weren't they all declared bloodriders in season 6. And that title requires them to avenge the death of their khal.

Comment: Not to mention, we do see a few of them while Jon is being escorted through the docks.